# Как перезаписывать TextView, а не выводить каждый раз новый?

Tags: android, textview

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView pi;
    int time = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       final TextView  pi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pi);
         Timer timert = new Timer();
       long delay = 0;
        long period = 1000;

        timert.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                time++;

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        pi.setText(pi.getText()+ " "+ time);

                    }

                });

            }

        },delay,period);


    }

}
```

При выполнении кода выводиться значение time. Но выводиться оно в строку 
типа 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... и т.д. 
Как сделать так чтобы выводилось новое значение а старое стиралось, то есть была только одна цифра ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pi.setText(time + "");` вместо `pi.setText(pi.getText()+ " "+ time);`

Comment: приложение не запускается

Comment: В Вашем коде я не вижу определения переменной time. Это сделано где-то вне этого куска? Какого она типа? Число? Тогда текст выводите как time+"". Я подправил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо помогло )